# How to restore a partial graph in tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to restore only the part of computation graph in tensorflow. My architecture contains two networks. The output of the first network is the input to the second network. The first network is pretrained and I want to restore from a checkpoint. I don't want to update the parameters of the first network as well. Is there an example that I can follow to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: does your checkpoint have weights trained for both the networks ? or only for the second one ?

Comment: Nope, the checkpoint has weights only for the first network. I have changed the variables in the first network with trainable=False. (after training them). I want to train the second network with the output of the first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have exact code for you task, but here is a short guide that may help you:

**First** you need to parse your network into `tf.GraphDef` format
code should like this:

```
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.FastGFile("path/to/graphdef") as f:
  s = f.read()
graph_def.ParseFromString(s)
```

or restore from a checkpoint/saved_mode then convert to `GraphDef` by:

```
tf.train.import_meta_graph('checkpoint.meta')
tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
```

now you have the graph_def

**Second**, extract subgraph of the `graph_def` with `tf.graph_util.extract_sub_graph`, you can specify the dest nodes which are you inputs to the second network as well.

**Last**, import the subgraph from second step with `tf.import_graph_def`.

**Also**, since you don't want to update the parameters for the first network, you can freeze its parameters with `tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't understand the last paragraph, on how to freeze the parameters ? I have changed the trainable=False for the weights and bias of the convolutional layers. Isn't that suffice ? And where to add the `convert_variables_to_constants` ?

Comment: @Sentient07 it is suffice in your case but a varaible with `trainable=False` only means that its value can't be changed with backprop and **can be** changed if you or someone else do `variable.assign(some_new_tensor)`, but if this variable is converted into a constant, no one can change its value. You can use `convert_variables_to_constants` anywhere before you import it into python console with `tf.image_graph_def`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Jie.Zhou I have another question. what is "path/to/graphdef" ? As in what should I replace it with ?

Comment: how do you save your network, isn't it a `.pb` file? "path/to/graphdef" is the path to this file.

Comment: I have created a checkpoint, using ckpt. I have .meta as well

Comment: `meta_graph_def = tf.MetaGraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile("path/to/graphdef") as f:
      s = f.read()
    meta_graph_def.ParseFromString(s)
    graph_def = meta_graph_def.graph_def`

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your answer Jie Zhou. It worked perfectly fine. I now want that graph for which i have checkpoints to be trainable as well. How do I go about doing that?